# Trouble with accessing express.js helpers from dust.js template

Tags: templates, express, helper, dust.js

I am playing with the node-express-boilerplate project and trying to convert it to use dust.js templates. I have dust.js render simple views with Express@3.x and dustjs-linkedin, however am stuck on converting helpers to be used inside dust.js templates.

I redefined the code starting @ https://github.com/mape/node-express-boilerplate/blob/master/server.js:144

to conform with the new Express@3.x version (using https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x as a guide), as such:

app.configure(function() {

```
   app.use(function(req, res, next) {
       res.locals.assetsCacheHashes = function(req, res) {
           return assetsMiddleware.cacheHashes;
       }
       res.locals.session = function(req, res) {
           return req.session;
       }
       res.locals.error = function(err, req, res, next) {

       // ...

       }
       next();
    });
});
```

I would assume that in dust.js template, I could use {session} to test the session or {assetsCacheHashes} to test and print them out, but that does not seem to be the case.

Any hints as to what I am doing incorrectly? Should I use dust.js helpers instead? If so, can someone suggest an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are defining your locals incorrectly.

Try this:

```
res.locals.session = req.session;

{{session}}
```

Comment: To clarify, the above suggestions will work if used inside of app.get(), e.g.,
    `app.get(
        ...
        res.locals.session = req.session;
        res.render('page');
        ...
    )`

Alternatively, one can pass context:
    `app.get(
        ...
        res.render('page', {'session': req.session});
        ...
    )`